# How to merge two Cell vertically after merging it horizontally before in asp.net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, openxml, export-to-excel, spreadsheet

I have a excel sheet. I have already merged two cell let's say from 
B19 - H19 and from B20 to H20. After mergeing this two cell how can I merge this two cells vertically? 
B19-B20??

```
 MergeReportDataCell(dsrow[col].ToString(), 0, cell.CellReference, excelColumnNames[innerColIndex], rowIndex, mergeCells, table.TableName);
 MergeReportDataCell(dsrow[col].ToString(), 0, cell.CellReference, excelColumnNames[innerColIndex], rowIndex + 1, mergeCells, table.TableName);
MergeReportDataCell("VerticalCellMerge", 0, cell.CellReference, excelColumnNames[innerColIndex], rowIndex, mergeCells, table.TableName);

 sheetPart.Worksheet.InsertAfter(mergeCells, sheetPart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().First());

}
```

```
public static void MergeReportDataCell(string cellNameWorkOrder,int head, StringValue cellReference, string columnIndex,uint rowIndex, MergeCells mergeCells, string tableName)
        {
            string cellAddress = "";
            string cellAddressTwo = "";

            if (mergeCells == null)
                mergeCells = new MergeCells();


                if( cellNameWorkOrder != "VerticalCellMerge")
                { 
                cellAddress = "B" + rowIndex.ToString();
                cellAddressTwo = "H" + rowIndex.ToString();
                }
                if( cellNameWorkOrder == "VerticalCellMerge")
                {
                    cellAddress = "B" + rowIndex.ToString();
                    cellAddressTwo = "B" + (rowIndex + 1).ToString();
                }

            mergeCells.Append(new MergeCell() { Reference = new StringValue(cellAddress + ":" + cellAddressTwo) });
        }
```

I tried using the above code it works fine if i don't use the vertical merge. But When I use vertical merge there is error in excel. How Can I solve this issue?

Comment: Will be good if you give the Error

Comment: There is no error is code, the excel file is downloaded but when I open the downloaded excel file is says ``` We Found a problem with some content in '*****.xlsx'. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click yes. ```  and if I click yes the cells aren't merged vertically

Comment: Something wrong with the formatted